# intialpose is in what reference?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What frame is the initialPose generated by setPose from navigation panel. Should I not do a translation to base_link first before using it. I am guessing the odom. So I would translate base_link -> odom before publishing tf and odometry.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81836/intialpose-is-in-what-reference?/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

amcl subscribes to initialpose topic and initial pose estimates are accepted in the global frame. You can see some part of the code inside initialPoseReceived function from amcl_node.cpp

```
  else if(tf_->resolve(msg->header.frame_id) != tf_->resolve(global_frame_id_))
  {
    ROS_WARN("Ignoring initial pose in frame \"%s\"; initial poses must be in the global frame, \"%s\"",
             msg->header.frame_id.c_str(),
             global_frame_id_.c_str());
    return;
  }
```

by default amcl sets global frame id to map

for more details check out [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's being sent in the frame that you set as the fixed frame in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pose sent is in reference to the fixed frame in RVIZ -- and therefore, you should almost certainly have your fixed frame set to "/map" as AMCL is determining the transform from base_link->odom->map, and the pose you send should be where base_link is in terms of map (so that the initial odom->map transform can be determined)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2